# Bootstrap: Nest label in button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `.label` nested in a `.btn`. When I `.pull-left` the `.label`, vertical alignment goes off by a few pixels (see JSfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/7476/)):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class='btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block'>
        <div class='label label-info pull-left'>BALANCE</div>
        <span>$10.00</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I keep the label vertically centered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div id='balance' class='btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block'>
        <span class="btn-info">BALANCE</span>
        <span>£<span class='value'>10.00</span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#balance .btn-info{
  padding:5px;
  border-radius:                    6px;
  -webkit-border-radius:            6px;
  -moz-border-radius:               6px;
}
```

Working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/7477/

Or you can add some class

```
#balance > div{
   padding-bottom:2px;
}
```